# Picker Accesibility. SWIFT UI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-picker, swiftui-text

I am trying disable dynamic text size from the accesibility system in a Menu picker but have yet to have any luck. I tried .font(.systemsize) dynamicTypeSize(...DynamicTypeSize.accessibility1), and .dynamicTypeSize(.medium) with no avail. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
`Menu {
                                            Picker("", selection: 
$StudentData.class){
                                                ForEach(class, id: \.self) {
                                                    Text($0)
                                                        .dynamicTypeSize(...DynamicTypeSize.accessibility1)
                                                        .tint(.green)
                                                
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } label: {
                                            HStack(spacing:0){
                                                Text(StudentData.class)
                                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.fill")
                                                    .foregroundColor(primary_color)
                                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                                            }
                                            .padding()
                                           
                      
                                            .background(Color(.white))
                                        }`
```